# Excel conditional formatting based on conditions

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on a personal project and have spent many hours researching colour formatting based on conditions. Unfortunately I have not been successful in achieving the end product.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help write a VBA code to address what I am trying to achieve below.

I have one named SaisieSO and two ranges. Range 1 (C:H) in which I enter six numbers and range 2 (N:R) in which I enter 5 numbers.

I would like in the worksheet in the Range (C: H) the cells to change colour based on the following conditions:

any cell in range (C:H) to be coloured red with white font if their value is equal to the value in N

any cell in range (C:H) to be coloured orange with black font if their value is equal to the value in O

any cell in range (C:H) to be coloured yellow with black font if their value is equal to the value in P

any cell in range (C:H) to be coloured blue with black font if their value is equal to the value in Q

any cell in range (C:H) to be coloured orange with black font if their value is equal to the value in R

I would like each time I add a new row with numbers in both ranges for the VBA code to colour the relevant cells as stipulated above.

Example

```
         Range (C:H) six numbers                     Range (N:R) 5 numbers

 Dates  
    
 C   D   E   F   G  H                                N   O   P   Q    R

02/08/2019  16  14  11  5   15  7                    4   8   6   3   7
07/08/2019  12  6   2   14  1   5                   12   6   15  5   13
08/08/2019  14  10  7   6   13  8                   14  10   12  7   9
09/08/2019  8   16  6   10  7   2                    7  16   2   8   4
```

I hope you are able to provide me an answer

Many thanks in advance

Bruno

Comment: I do not see why you could not achieve this with [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Answer (score 0):

I'm advising you not to use VBA, but to do this using conditional formatting, the basic feature of Excel, as explained in [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

You can simply write a formula, and when this formula gives "TRUE", then the conditional formatting will be applied.

E.g. in cell C2 I've put a value, and in cell N2 I've put the same one. I've then created a conditional formatting rule, based on this formula:

```
=(C2=$N2)
```

When C2 equals N2 the result of this formula yields "TRUE", so the conditional formatting will be applied.

Why the dollarsign in front of column N? Well, you seem to want to use conditional formatting for the range C:H. When you drag to the right (e.g. for column D), your formula changes into:

```
=(D2=$N2)
```

As you see, dragging to the right changes your column reference from C to D, but the N is left fixed, because of the dollar sign. This is known as absolute cell referencing, and is explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

Comment: Good evening, I have followed and applied what you mentioned in your reply and lo and behold it worked like a dream. Thanks to you I have learnt something new and saved myself hours of work. I can not thank you enough.

Comment: @Bruno: I'm glad I could help. Please upvote and/or accept my answer, so it might become more useful for other people who have similar issues.